# How can I disable a tkinter frame upon pressing a button?

Tags: python, user-interface, events, tkinter, frames

For my bigger application I have a Tk Frame that spawns upon right clicking. I want all the focus of the window to be directed towards this frame (If the user clicks on a button on the parent then nothing happens) and then when the frame is destroyed I want it to go back to normal. I created a minimal example to demonstrate what I have tried to do and it is not working.

I simply want the Root button (Say hi) to be disabled after clicking Disable Outer.

```
import tkinter as tk

class app(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent=parent

        toggler = tk.Button(self,text='DISABLE OUTER',command=self.toggleMain)
        toggler.pack(padx=20,pady=20)    

    def toggleMain(self):

        status= self.parent.grab_status()
        if not status:
            print('Outer Is Disabled (Hi Should not work)')
            self.parent.grab_set_global()
        else:
            print('Outer is Enabled (Hi should work)')
            self.parent.grab_release()

root = tk.Tk()

app = app(root,bg='red')
app.pack()


def SayHi():
    print('Hi There')

f=tk.Button(root,text='Say Hi',command=SayHi)
f.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what it is you are trying to do, but if all you want to do is disable the button that says ""Say Hi" is to disable it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class app(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent,*args,**kwargs)
        self.parent=parent

        toggler = tk.Button(self,text='DISABLE OUTER',command=self.toggleMain)
        toggler.pack(padx=20,pady=20)

    def toggleMain(self):

        status= self.parent.grab_status()
        if not status:
            print('Outer Is Disabled (Hi Should not work)')
            self.grab_set()
        else:
            print('Outer is Enabled (Hi should work)')
            self.grab_release()

root = tk.Tk()

app = app(root,bg='red')
app.pack()


def SayHi():
    print('Hi There')

f=tk.Button(root,text='Say Hi',command=SayHi)
f.pack()

root.mainloop(
```

Comment: This is a minimal example, In my real program I have hundreds of different event bindings. I couldnt possibly unbind them all and rebind them all. I need to disable all of them with a method. I have read documentation and grab_set_global() does this. However, in my example it is not working. Thanks for the comment regardless

Comment: Do you need to use grab_set_global()? what about just using grab_set()

Comment: I updated the code above to use grab_set, try that and see if it works for you.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, don't know why I didn't see that. With the line ```status= self.grab_status()``` it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!